# Bluetooth not working for HP dv 7 6b32 us

Tags: gnome, hp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome. I dual booted it with Windows 7. When I try to launch the Bluetooth Application, I get a message in the launched app "No Bluetooth Adapters Found". The app thus does not give me any options of launching Bluetooth. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your have a hardware switch to turn signal on/off (Air plane mode). Or a FN key to turn it on/off

Run this command     `rfkill list all`
to check if BT is turned off via a kill switch

Also check this to see if Ubuntu recognized your BT.
[How can I tell if my laptop has Bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301458/how-can-i-tell-if-my-computer-has-bluetooth/301856#301856)

Does BT work in Windows 7 boot?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I checked and found my laptop does not have BT. I was under the misconception that I had BT because in my windows I had an app of BT. But it does not work either. I should have had a look in my manual before asking the question. My bad!

Comment: please mark as answer if this helped you. thx