# Cannot find bluetooth device, although there should be one

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, hp

According to my [laptop specifications](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC-series/5401225/model/6463650/document/c03975086/), I do have a bluetooth device. However, I am unable to find it. I have tried the standard command line approach as given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301458/how-can-i-tell-if-my-laptop-has-bluetooth) or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup#Manual_Discovery). As requested, the output from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

and from `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:571a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Blueman applet does not detect one either.

The truth is that I never worried about bluetooth, but now it would be very useful. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.

I didn't buy the laptop from HP but from a distributor. Have I been cheated? (It seems my graphic card is not the one stated in that website either!) It's too late to complain, as my warranty expired one year ago.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You have a BT device. It is built into `Ralink corp. RT3290`. But there it is hard to find drivers for it, that work for the current kernels.

Comment: Oh, I see. So in Windows it would work. Am I basically screwed?

Comment: It is possible to get it working, but not quite easy.

Comment: Ok, will google that. In the mean time, I found this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working, but it is about wifi. If you have a suggestion, welcome!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I don't know if it will ever work as the manufacturer is reluctant to release info