# Bluetooth is not able to find devices on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I am not able to find and connect to bluetooth devices.

Output from command : `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; rfkill list`

```
13:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:930b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
49: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:

1. Type either one of the following commands:

   ```
   dmesg | grep -i blue
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo lsusb |grep Bluetooth
   ```

   The command output will suggest whether your Bluetooth firmware is missing or not. It will be something like:

   ```
   Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
   ```

   Also see: [How can I tell if my laptop has Bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301458/how-can-i-tell-if-my-laptop-has-bluetooth)
2. If you are indeed missing a firmware (.hcd) file, then try to search and copy the required .hcd file to `/lib/firmware/brcm`.

   Also see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743336).