# No Bluetooth Found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3470 and it does not recognize bluetooth. Hardware specification on Dell's page: 389-BEHN : 802.11bgn + Bluetooth 4.0, 2.4 GHz, 1x1.

When I open the settings it says: No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.

I have tried:

```
sudo blueman-manager
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 16.22.15 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 16.22.15 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

There are no additional drivers available for download.

Additional information:

```
sudo lshw | grep -A 10 "blue"
               capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.10
               configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 5.4.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 5.04
            capabilities: usb-3.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=10000Mbit/s
```

.

```
dmesg |egrep -i "blue|fw|firm|hci" 
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TPM Final Events table missing or invalid
[    0.522136] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.522138] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.522145] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.522152] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.522153] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.522159] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.522163] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.522362] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.522367] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.523468] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000009810
[    0.523475] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.523659] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.523660] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.525174] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.525177] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.525178] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    0.525206] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.525207] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.813299] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    0.827290] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    0.827291] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm clo only pio slum part ems deso sadm sds apst 
[    0.859458] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    0.864068] scsi host0: ahci
[    0.864329] scsi host1: ahci
[    0.864538] scsi host2: ahci
[    0.864744] scsi host3: ahci
[    0.864851] scsi host4: ahci
[    0.864950] scsi host5: ahci
[    1.139466] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.415443] usb 1-14: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    9.413222] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.413232] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.413234] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.413235] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.413237] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.502605] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[   46.970961] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   46.970964] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   46.970972] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  191.667475] Lockdown: fwupd: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

.

```
dmesg | grep Bluetooth                                                                 ✔ │ 09:50:21   
[    9.413222] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.413232] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.413234] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.413235] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.413237] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   46.970961] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   46.970964] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   46.970972] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

The command bellow returns nothing:

```
sudo lspci | grep -A 10 "blue"
```

.

```
ls /sys/bus/sdio/drivers
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A 10 "blue"` to your question. You could also add `sudo lspci | grep -A 10 "blue"`.

Comment: @zx485 question updated with additional information.

Comment: Also please post the output of dmesg |egrep -i "blue|fw|firm|hci"   and the output of 
ls /sys/bus/sdio/drivers
   Are you sure you actually have bluetooth hardware on the machine?

Comment: @ubfan1 question updated with additional information. Yes, I'm sure. It was working on Windows.

Comment: Do you have the Bluetooth driver installed?

Comment: @Ruby How can I check? I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and everything on Software & Updates > Additional Drivers (It says No additional drivers available).

Comment: Paste result from `dmesg | grep Bluetooth`

Comment: @Ruby question updated with additional information.

Comment: In the dmesg it posts a message when it loads a firmware for a specific device, like in my dmesg ( meaning when I do `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`, read on net what this command does if you do not know about it ), there is one line `[   23.134685] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq`, there is no such thing in your output, so probably a missing firmware I think.

Comment: You can just do `sudo dmesg | less` and read the whole stuff to double check it if you want.

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT Do you know how I can fix it? Before coming here I have searched for how Install drivers but I did not have success.

Comment: @RhonanCarneiro You can manually install the driver by downloading the ***.deb*** file and installing it with ***dpkg -i*** command.

Comment: First you should try the above mentioned approach. If it does not work then  
@RhonanCarneiro you should edit your question by stating your laptop version and what bluetooth hardware is in it ( search for net if you are able to find it ), then asking for how to install the required driver.

Comment: @Ruby Do you know where I can download this .deb file?

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT Edited question with hardware specification. Hardware specification on Dell's page: 389-BEHN : 802.11bgn + Bluetooth 4.0, 2.4 GHz, 1x1.

Comment: @RhonanCarneiro, I have been using Debian for a while now, it is available as firmware non-free package on Debian, I can't give much clue on Ubuntu.

Comment: @RhonanCarneiro, Check [this](https://dev-pages.info/ubuntu-bluetooth/) out.

Comment: @Ruby It fails on the first step because my lsusb | grep Bluetooth returns nothing.

Comment: @RhonanCarneiro see the 2nd comment of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/301473/834982) answer for possible reason of bluetooth not showing in lsusb.

Also for installing bluetooth firmware/drivers see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) official ubuntu page.

Comment: The link on official ubuntu page talks about old versions... I tried anyway, but it did not solve. As I commented before, this computer has bluetooth, It was working on Windows.

Comment: I have boot Ubuntu from pendrive (the same used to install it), and the Bluetooth works fine.

Comment: I have this problem too on ubuntu 18. Sometimes when I restart the computer, bluetooth becomes available. This also applies to wifi.